# Apple Swift Singleton implementation

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I know about that "one line singleton" approach

```
final class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
    private init() {}
}
```

But if you will look into standard singleton objects like `UIApplication` you will see this :

[image]

I'm curious what code Apple using to create singletones.

Comment: What you see is only the public interface, that allows no conclusion about how Apple implements the method. The implementation is not open source, so unless an Apple engineer decides to reveal it here, we cannot answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

@Michael Dautermann's answer is correct if you're looking for Apple's recommendation for how to write singletons in Swift.

If however, you're wondering why singleton's from Cocoa Touch look the way they do, the answer is simple. They aren't written in Swift, they're written in Objective-C, and in Objective-C, singletons are typically written as class methods. Usually something along the lines of this.

```
+ (UIApplication * _Nonnull)sharedApplication
{  
    // This is a typical example of how one might to this in Objective-C
    // but we have no way of knowing what code Apple actually has here. 
    // All we know is that there is a sharedApplication class method.
    static UIApplication *sharedApplication = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedApplication = [[UIApplication alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedApplication;
}
```

So it may be true that they are recommending different ways of writing singleton's in Swift, but what you're looking at is an Objective-C singleton bridged to Swift.

Comment: I know it is correct way to create singleton, but question is different. Nice point about bridging btw.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's official sample describes [Singleton](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH49-SW1) setup in Swift as:

```
class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
}
```

or

```
class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance: Singleton = {
        let instance = Singleton()
        // setup code
        return instance
    }()
}
```

which you'll find in the "Singleton" section of ["Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns" in their Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID6).

Comment: my question is not "how to create singletone", it is about how Apple implement singletones in their code.

Comment: thanks for the downvote Andrei!  If Apple makes their style guide public, you can believe that this is how they tell their engineers to do the code internally.  Or do you want to see the actual source code of how a singleton is done within the OS?  I don't believe any part of iOS or MacOS is done in Swift yet.

Comment: no offence, but this looks like if someone asks specific question about diet and you answer like "just eat less" ))

Comment: @AndreiMalygin IMO a better response, that is if you want an answer, it to add a comment explaining why the answer is not what you are looking for. Many times a question is not clear to developers who will answer it and a down vote will cut off further help instead of an improved answer. Please only down vote an answer if it is incorrect, to may be helpful to others.

Comment: @zaph i don't see how this question could be interpreted like "help, I don't know how to create a singleton in Swift". There is sample code in the question already.

Comment: @AndreiMalygin well surely no one is going to help you with that attitude for sure. How about no being a dick, and explaining someone why that is not the correct answer. And btw, if this is the recommended guidelines this is probably how apple is creating singletons, not that any of us can prove this in any way.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
class Singleton {

    class func sharedInstance() -> Singleton {
        struct Static {
            static var instance: Singleton? = nil
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = self()
        }

        return Static.instance!
    }

    @required init() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How Apple implemented Singletons can be read in their blog [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7).

> The lazy initializer for a global variable (also for static members of
>   structs and enums) is run the first time that global is accessed, and
>   is launched as dispatch_once to make sure that the initialization is
>   atomic. This enables a cool way to use dispatch_once in your code:
>   just declare a global variable with an initializer and mark it
>   private.

so basically they still use the dispatch_once call as in the Objective-C era, but now it's handled behind the scenes by the Swift compiler.